# Notify about an edit when it changes MathJax, even if not "substantive"

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications, mathjax

I think that whenever a post gets edited by someone other than the person who wrote it and when the edit changes a MathJax formula, then, no matter how small the change was technically, the author of the post should be warned that that editon took place. A small change in a mathematical formula can have huge consequences.

Comment: I don't know about questions part, but I did get the notification If my answer was edited.